# Liftmaster garage opener keypad stops working when temp drops below 40 degrees F

Tags: garage-door

Lift master garage opener keypad stops working when temps drop below 40 degrees F. The hand held remotes work. it was installed new in 2017.  Batteries have been replaced and still not working.

Comment: Ask a question and tell us the model number and the age of the keypad.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried replacing the battery?   A weak battery might work when it's warm, but, like all batteries, their performance is reduced substantially at lower temps.